# A Quiz Question

Tags: words

Some days ago I asked a quiz question and the comments I received indicated that the question was unclear. I now have some clarification from the quiz-setter, which I hope will help.

The question was basically "Which one of these words cannot be a Japanese word - Alibi, Gala, Gnu, Hero, Mate, Star, Stun?"  The clarification for the question is as follows "I suggest you have a look at a list of Japanese words and see if you can spot a pattern - one that just one of the examples given doesn't fit"

Does this help you to help me!?

Many thanks for your ongoing assistance with this.

Peter

Comment: If you feel your existing question can be improved and perhaps reopened, please consider [editing your existing post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64686/which-of-these-words-could-not-be-a-japanese-word); please do not post a new copy of question.